# How to override Setting "accessibility/large text”in my app's layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, settings

I have my app's layout optimized for a variety of device sizes in dp. However I did not factored in that there is a "large text" setting in accessibility that can would mess up my layout. I current set my textsize in sp in my layouts. I checked around some app and their text size seems to not be effected by the "large text" setting. How do I program my layout so that it doesn't increase the text size when user set it to "large text"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the user has requested larger fonts, there is probably a reason for that, such as impaired vision. Talented developers will design their layouts to take different `TextView` sizes into account, whether those sizes are based on font scale, language, or other reasons.

Comment: CommonsWare, that's understandable however I've already increased my text size to be larger than default value to utilize the blank spaces. That's why the setting messed with my layout, because I am out of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just set textsize to dp instead of sp for the text that you don't want to get resized by the accessibility setting.